# How to unstack dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pandas df with the columns "Item","Year","Value" which has 708 rows. I want to reshape this into a df with 59 rows and 12 columns.
This is what it looks like now (simplified):

```
Item, Year, Value
Apple, 2001, 5
Apple, 2002, 4
Apple, 2003, 7
Apple, 2004, 2
Orange, 2001, 1
Orange, 2002, 5
Orange, 2003, 2
Orange, 2004, 3
```

And the result I need is:

```
  Year, Apple, Orange
    2001, 5, 1
    2002, 4, 5
    2003, 7, 2
    2004, 2, 3
```

How can I go about achieving this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set `Year` and `Item` to be the index first and then it's pretty easy from there:

```
In [331]: df.set_index(["Year", "Item"]).unstack()['Value']
Out[331]:
Item  Apple  Orange
Year
2001      5       1
2002      4       5
2003      7       2
2004      2       3
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
print(df.pivot(index="Year", columns="Item", values="Value"))
```

Prints:

```
Item  Apple  Orange
Year               
2001      5       1
2002      4       5
2003      7       2
2004      2       3
```

---

To save as CSV:

```py
x = df.pivot(index="Year", columns="Item", values="Value").reset_index()
x.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Saves `data.csv`:

```
Year,Apple,Orange
2001,5,1
2002,4,5
2003,7,2
2004,2,3
```